# Windows Phone Hub Control Height Issue

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I'm having a few problems laying out my phone page which contains a Hub control.  The height of the Hub control doesn't seem to be consistent with it's parent container.

To see the issue for yourselves follow the steps below:

- Create a new project.
- Choose Store Apps - Hub App (Universal Template).
- Goto the Windows 8.1 part of the project and view the HubPage.xaml unit.
- Place the cursor in the Grid element on line 35 and view it's layout properties in the property window.
- Notice that it's VerticalAlignment is set to stretch and it's height is set to Auto (768).
- Now do the same with the Hub element on line 41 and it's height is also set to Auto (768) as you would expect.
- Now go to the HubPage.xaml unit in the Windows Phone 8.1 part of the project.
- Place the cursor in the Grid element on line 73 and view it's layout properties in the property window.
- Notice that it's VerticalAlignment is set to stretch and it's height is set to Auto (640).
- Now go to the Hub element on the next line (74) and although it's VerticalAlignment is set to Stretch, it's height is set to Auto (666.666625976562).

How can the Hub element be bigger than it's parent when everything is stretched vertically.  What's worse is that the difference between the height of the child and the height of the parent seems to change when the phone switches to landscape mode.  This is really causing me issues with my app layout and I'm struggling to understand why it is happening.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words... Show your XAML and a screenshot of your page.

Comment: I don't understand.  The steps are very easy to reproduce.  Is anyone else having trouble seeing this?